# What is the error between NTP stratums?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

I read that NTP syncs machines upto 100 ms accuracy on WAN (given in following links - http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

Is the error of 100 ms (or sync difference) at each NTP stratum?
If not then how does NTP ensure that error doesn't build up to lower layers?

I know I am missing something from the NTP protocol here, can someone please point out what? Does it have anything to do with root delay and root dispersion or they are just used to reject the candidate servers?

Answer (score 0):

100ms is just an illustrative value giving a typical upper level of
what is to be expected with current network technology.

Basically the delta among 2 ntp nodes is determined by the asymmetry of 
of the network connection to and from one node to the other.

Dispersion measures the error over time on measuring the clock of 
the (source) ntp server with the (local) clock of the ntp client.

Thus, with ATM or other kind of store-and-forward components within the network path the achievable accuracy is far superior 
than with low latency broadcast links that might be present within a LAN.

The 100ms are not to be taken as a value per level, but are 
what is to be expected along
a usual (low depth) synchronisation tree.
(I have not seen more than 5 levels being used in real live)

root delay is the total delay to the time source in use.
root dispersion is the maximum error alongt the path to this time source.

For detailed explanation on how error (and jitter and dispersion) are 
calculated and interact, please have a look at the specification documents.

E.g.: [RFC 5905: Network Time Protocol Version 4: Protocol and Algorithms Specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt)